# auto generate a code in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using microsoft sql server. I would like to generate a code for the items of the table I'm using I want the code to look like this AA/034, AA/365......

AA is a simple serie of number that will not change and the 034 or 365 is the number of the days in a year so the code will not be unique ; the same code will be attributed to all the results entered during the same day. for example if today is january 28 the code generated will be AA/028. can you please help me with the SQL query for this code.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the day of the year using the [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) method in T-SQL.  So to get the contents of the field:

```
("AA/" + DATEPART(dy, date_goes_here)) AS datecode
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your date column is called `EnteredDate`

`Select 'AA/' + Right('000' + Cast(DATEPART(dy, EnteredDate)as varchar(3)),3)`

Comment: Yeah, this is actually a better and more complete solution than mine.